# FB insights stream publish users

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I'd like to get a list of users who have shared my app on to their streams. Facebook insights gives me the number of users who have published the story but I'd like to get their usernames as well. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this is simply not possible! Facebook doesn't give access to this information unless you explicitly get permission from the user to examine their feed with the [`read_stream` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/). Even if you did, you would have to scan each individual users feed to see if they have the shared post.

As I see it, the insights service is more statistical information that user information.

You can however see by manually clicking on the number of shares next to the post on Facebook. There is a difference between the type of data Facebook shows users and the data that they make available to applications via the API. This is to make sure that no applications take part in data mining and simply collecting as much data as they can on every user.